# Implement entrySet for a Map without keys

Tags: java, dictionary

I have written a `TrieMap<V> implements Map<String,V>` class which is obviously keyed from Strings. This works fine.

I want to enhance it to be keyed with the more general `CharSequence`. I believe I have managed to achieve the transform apart from one final issue, I can't create objects of type `K`.

The signature must now therefore become`TrieMap<K extends CharSequence,V> implements Map<K,V>`. The problem is, as I am sure you know, a `TrieMap` does not actually store the original keys. (In fact that is one of its main values, it can therefore often take up much less space than an ordinary map.)

To implement `Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet()` I therefore must somehow manufacture objects of type `K`. Is there any way that can be achieved?

Comment: @dfb: the difficulty is not creating the keys as instances of String. The difficulty is creating keys of type K, without knowing what K is.

Comment: Side question: What is the advantage of the question/answer below over `TrieMap<V> implements Map<CharSequence,V>`?

Comment: @dfb - not sure what you are asking but the benefit of a factory method is that the creator provides the mechanism for making the key because, due to type erasure, only the creator knows what type is in use. I feel a little like VGer in Star Trek now. :)

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - Right, but the class doesn't need to specify K for what you're doing, only the interface.  If you know it's a subtype of CharSequence, no generics required for the key. Then you use your own implementation (e.g., String) and the consumer can do whatever he pleases with the interface

Comment: @dfb - re Side Question - The benefit is that user can do stuff like `Map<StringBuffer,Object> map; ...; for ( StringBuffer s : map.keySet() ) { ... }`. In your scenario they would have to do `...; for ( CharSequence ...` which would be at least irritating if not error prone.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I see. Disadvantage is that you perform some sort of conversion from the generated internal representation of the keyset (not just the tree) to their expected concrete class, instead of just returning whatever you build up from the Trie.  I see why you would pass in a StringBuffer to build keys from a Trie internally, but having mutable keys is error prone, too. If you're using a parameterized type in the implementation of TrieMap, you still are working with CharSeq. (put/get). Pedantic point, but I'd argue this couples the implementation to the interface.

Comment: @dfb - In a `Trie` structure there is actually no keyset at all. The key you provide for your lookup in the map is used character by character to trace the location of the value you are seeking. My representation of the keyset is actually merely an algorithm that walks the Trie structure, at no time does the keyset ever actually exist. For the keyset I must, however, generate 'fake' keys on the fly and these factories are used to build them of the expected type. In my opinion the use of a factory in this instance is actually performing a **decouple** of the implementation from the interface.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - I got the Trie part, but you have to decide on a concrete implementation of whatever class you use to build the fake keys (String, StringBuilder, whatever). Now you have to perform a conversion via the KeyBuilder to whatever the type the user provides (StringBuilder -> String , for example). You can make a KeyBuilder class, then TrieMap gets more complex and inflexible with regards to other subtypes of CharSequence.  If you do this, then your internal representation is also somewhat dependent on the client.  Depends on your use case, it seems. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define the following interface:

```
public interface KeyBuilder<K extends CharSequence> {
    public K build(CharSequence value);
}
```

and provide an implementation of the interface to the `TrieMap` constructor. When you need to build a new K instance, you ask the interface to do it.

You might use something more apt to your data structure as the parameter to the `build` method, CharSequence is only a possibility. IF you want to do something more complex, you could structure it like this:

```
public interface KeyFactory<K extends CharSequence> {
    public KeyBuilder<K> newBuilder();
}

public interface KeySequence<K extends CharSequence> {
    public KeySequence<K> append(char value);
    public K build();
}
```

With `String` implementations:

```
public class StringKeyFactory<String> {
    public KeyBuilder<String> newBuilder() {
        return new KeyBuilder<String>() {
            private final StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            public KeySequence<String> append(char value) {
                s.append(value);
                return this;
            }
            public String build() {
                return s.toString();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: That should work. Can you think of any way I could pre-build factories for the most common CharSequence implementors such as `String` and `StringBuilder` and automagically pick the right one? I suppose that could be a factory of mine such as `newStringMap()` etc. It is such a shame I cannot interrogate the generic types in my constructor.

Comment: I think the static constructor is the easiest and cleanest choice.

Comment: I chose to demand a much simpler interface, a method `K toK(CharSequence key)` that creates a `K` out of the `CharSequence`. Otherwise this was a perfect solution.

Comment: If your `Trie` can easily provide a `CharSequence`, the simpler interface is definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't see how it would be possible without taking a `Factory<K>` as argument in your constructor. This `Factory<K>` would have the responsibility of creating instances of `K` based on the elements you have in the `TrieMap`.